# Why is my 'postInfo' state variable null when calling a function, despite being updated correctly in React Native and Firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a React Native application using Firebase for data storage. I have a two components, let's call it Post and CommentSheet, where I display posts along with their details and a bottom sheet to display and upload comments.

The problem arises when I attempt to post a comment for a post. Although I can successfully log the postInfo in the useEffect when it updates, I encounter an issue when calling a function (onUpload) from another component (commentSheet). After testing, the postInfo prop appears to be null when the function is invoked, however it is logged correctly when used in useEffect in either components.

Here's a simplified flow of my code:

1. The openCommentSheet function is called from a child component (Post) when a user clicks on a comment icon.
2. getPostDetails fetches post information using onSnapshot and setPostInfo is called to store information.
3. postInfo is passed to commentSheet component in-order to perform its own functions.
4. Despite logging the correct postInfo in the useEffect, when onUpload is invoked, the postInfo is null.

Here's what I think are the relevant snippets of code:

```
const Post = ({post, navigation, getPostDetails, openCommentSheet, closeCommentSheet}) => {
...
const PostFooter = ({handleGoing, post, openCommentSheet, getPostDetails, navigation}) => (
  ...
      <TouchableOpacity 
        onPress={(() => {
          openCommentSheet(post.postID) //This works fine
        })}>

        <Image style={styles.footerIcon}
          source={require('../../assets/icons/comment.png')}>
        </Image>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      ...
}
```

```
const HomeScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  const [postInfo, setPostInfo] = useState(null);
  const [postID, setPostID] = useState(null);
  const [comments, setComments] = useState(null);

  const bottomSheetRef = useRef(null);

  const handleSheetChanges = useCallback(index => {
    console.log('handleSheetChanges', index);
    {
      index == -1
        ? (setComments(null), setPostInfo(null), setPostID(null))
        : null;
    }
  }, []);

  const handleClosePress = () => {
    bottomSheetRef.current.close();
  };

  const handleOpenPress = () => {
    bottomSheetRef.current.snapToIndex(1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Updated postInfo:', postInfo);
  }, [postInfo]);

  const openCommentSheet = async postID => {
    try {
      getPostDetails(postID);
      getCommentDetails(postID);
      handleOpenPress();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching post information:', error);
    }
  };

  const getPostDetails = async postID => {
    onSnapshot(doc(db, 'posts', postID), doc => {
      // console.log("Current data: ", doc.data());
      setPostInfo(doc.data());
    });
  };

  const getCommentDetails = async postID => {
    const commentsCollection = collection(db, 'posts', postID, 'comments');
    const commentsQuery = query(
      commentsCollection,
      orderBy('createdAt', 'asc'),
    );

    onSnapshot(commentsQuery, snap => {
      console.log(snap.docs.length);
      setComments(
        snap.docs.map(comment => ({id: comment.id, ...comment.data()})),
      );
    });
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Header navigation={navigation} />
      <PostScreen
        navigation={navigation}
        openCommentSheet={openCommentSheet}
        closeCommentSheet={handleClosePress}
      />
      <BottomTabs navigation={navigation} icons={BottomTabIcons} />
      <CommentSheet
        bottomSheetRef={bottomSheetRef}
        postInfo={postInfo}
        comments={comments}
        postID={postID}
        handleSheetChanges={handleSheetChanges}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
...

export default HomeScreen;
```

```
// CommentSheet.js
import React, {useCallback, useEffect, useMemo, useRef, useState} from 'react';
import {Text, View, Pressable, StyleSheet, Alert} from 'react-native';
import BottomSheet, {
  BottomSheetTextInput,
  BottomSheetFlatList,
  BottomSheetFooter,
  BottomSheetBackdrop,
} from '@gorhom/bottom-sheet';
import {
  addDoc,
  collection,
  collectionGroup,
  doc,
  onSnapshot,
  serverTimestamp,
  setDoc,
} from '@firebase/firestore';
import {Formik} from 'formik';
import {Divider} from 'react-native-elements';
import Comment from './Comment';
import {auth, db} from '../../firebase';

const CommentSheet = ({
  bottomSheetRef,
  handleSheetChanges,
  postInfo,
  comments,
}) => {
  const loadingIndicator = (
    <Text style={styles.headerText}>Loading comments...</Text>
  );
  const snapPoints = useMemo(() => ['25%', '50%', '75%', '100%'], []);

  const [postData, setPostData] = useState({});

  const renderBackdrop = useCallback(
    props => (
      <BottomSheetBackdrop
        appearsOnIndex={0}
        disappearsOnIndex={-1}
        {...props}
      />
    ),
    [],
  );

  const onUpload = async comment => {
    const postID = postInfo.postID;
    try {
      const commentInput = {
        user: auth.currentUser.displayName,
        profile_picture: auth.currentUser.photoURL,
        owner_uid: auth.currentUser.uid,
        owner_email: auth.currentUser.email,
        comment: comment,
        createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
      };

      const commentRef = await addDoc(
        collection(db, 'posts', postID, 'comments'),
        commentInput,
      );

      const commentID = commentRef.id;

      await setDoc(
        doc(db, 'posts', postID, 'comments', commentID),
        {commentID},
        {merge: true},
      );

      console.log('Data Submitted');
    } catch (error) {
      Alert.alert('This is awkward...', error.message);
    }
  };

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   console.log(postInfo);
  // });

  const clearTextInput = formik => {
    formik.resetForm();
  };

  const renderFooter = useCallback(
    props => (
      <Formik
        initialValues={{comment: ''}}
        onSubmit={async (values, formik) => {
          console.log('Before onUpload:', postInfo); // returns postInfo as null 
          await onUpload(values.comment).then(clearTextInput(formik)); // doesn't work :(
        }}>
        {({handleBlur, handleChange, handleSubmit, values}) => (
          <>
            <BottomSheetFooter
              {...props}
              // bottomInset={24}
            >
              <Divider />
              <View style={styles.footerContainer}>
                <BottomSheetTextInput
                  style={styles.input}
                  multiline={true}
                  maxLength={200}
                  placeholder="Add a comment..."
                  onChangeText={handleChange('comment')}
                  onBlur={handleBlur('comment')}
                  value={values.comment}
                />
                <Pressable
                  style={({pressed}) => [
                    styles.footerButton,
                    {
                      backgroundColor: pressed ? '#1c414f' : '#52bce3',
                      opacity: values.comment.trim() === '' ? 0.5 : 1,
                    },
                  ]}
                  onPress={handleSubmit}
                  disabled={values.comment.trim() === ''}>
                  <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Post</Text>
                </Pressable>
              </View>
            </BottomSheetFooter>
          </>
        )}
      </Formik>
    ),
    [],
  );

  return (
    <BottomSheet
      ref={bottomSheetRef}
      index={-1}
      snapPoints={snapPoints}
      onChange={handleSheetChanges}
      enablePanDownToClose={true}
      backdropComponent={renderBackdrop}
      keyboardBlurBehavior="restore"
      android_keyboardInputMode="adjustResize"
      footerComponent={renderFooter}>
      <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.commentHeader}>COMMENTS</Text>
        {comments ? (
          <>
            <BottomSheetFlatList
              data={comments}
              renderItem={({item}) => (
                <>
                  <Comment comment={item} />
                </>
              )}
            />
          </>
        ) : (
          loadingIndicator
        )}
      </View>
    </BottomSheet>
  );
};

...

export default CommentSheet;
```

Here are all the relevant console.logs:

```
 LOG  Updated postInfo: null 
 LOG  handleSheetChanges 1
 LOG  Updated postInfo: {"caption": "My nephew", "comments": [], "createdAt": {"nanoseconds": 574000000, "seconds": 1700339789}, "fileName": "rn_image_picker_lib_temp_abe4a703-c70b-462d-8ee3-120e404b21ab.jpg", "imageUrl": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/motive-8c0ca.appspot.com/o/OmWrXsgS9ibbuHATrP9AEYB9bvK2%2Fposts%2Frn_image_picker_lib_temp_abe4a703-c70b-462d-8ee3-120e404b21ab.jpg?alt=media&token=fe89366c-2465-4bdb-a292-f83b2030e878", "owner_email": "cezey01@gmail.com", "owner_uid": "OmWrXsgS9ibbuHATrP9AEYB9bvK2", "postID": "AT1TYlXFLyB0MxoYcosX", "profile_picture": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/motive-8c0ca.appspot.com/o/OmWrXsgS9ibbuHATrP9AEYB9bvK2%2Fpfp?alt=media&token=1f62f214-99ed-44b0-af06-af83cacee6ed", "user": "naechebango", "users_going": []}
 LOG  3
 LOG  Before onUpload: null
```

Initially postInfo is null, the comment sheet is opened, useEffect updates it, but it still says no when trying to upload a comment in the commentSheet component.

For some reason it gets fixed after making any change in the code and saving the code. I assume it's because the component gets re-rendered with a full postInfo object already initialised.

Comments are displayed as intended so I know it's not an issue of data retrieval.

I am using gorhom's bottom sheet for the comment components if that helps.

Comment: Is PostFooter defined inside of Post ?  If so, I strongly recommend that you move PostFooter to its own file.  Otherwise, PostFooter (a function) gets recompiled with each render (each invocation of the function) of Post.  This would lead to all sorts of weirdness in terms of variable scope, etc.

Comment: Another thing we'd want to understand is the relationship of all those components in terms of the "component tree" of your React app.  Which components are "ancestors" of which other components.

Comment: You've used `onSnapshot` in a few places without returning its unsubscribe function and calling it to detach the realtime updates listener once you are done with it. You need to make sure that you detach this listener properly to prevent data conflicts and unexpected behaviour. Alternatively, if you intended to only get the data once, you can use `getDoc` instead of `onSnapshot` and adjust your helper methods as appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a look at where your "Before upload" log is:

```js
const renderFooter = useCallback(
  props => (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{comment: ''}}
      onSubmit={async (values, formik) => {
        console.log('Before onUpload:', postInfo);
        await onUpload(values.comment).then(clearTextInput(formik));
      }}>
      { /* ... */ }
    </Formik>
  ),
  [],
);
```

Because you've used the `useCallback` hook and passed in `[]` as the second argument, you've effectively instructed React to create your callback, but only use the callback generated on the first render.

Taking a look at your useState calls for `postInfo`:

```js
const [postInfo, setPostInfo] = useState(null);
```

We can see that on your first render, `postInfo` will be set to `null`, and in turn that value is used in the returned `renderFooter` callback when it is parsed for the first time.

On later renders, that callback is regenerated with the new value, but because the callback is already defined, the fresh callback is discarded because none of the properties passed in as the second argument changed. To have React use the new value whenever `postInfo` changes, you need to pass in `[postInfo]` as the second argument to `useCallback`.

This results in the following:

```js
// renderFooter is now changed whenever postInfo changes
const renderFooter = useCallback(
  props => (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{comment: ''}}
      onSubmit={async (values, formik) => {
        console.log('Before onUpload:', postInfo);
        await onUpload(values.comment).then(clearTextInput(formik));
      }}>
      { /* ... */ }
    </Formik>
  ),
  [postInfo] // <-- use new value when postInfo changes
);
```

It's then up to your BottomSheet component to handle rendering the new footer.

Comment: Oh my goodness it's always one small line of code that fixes weeks of debugging. Thanks for the solution. Can you recommend any resources that have an in-depth explaination of how react hooks work or just react in general? I've kinda just been winging it since graduating earlier this year.

Comment: @naechebango I've got into the habit of associating the thought "but it didn't update" with "check hook dependencies". I find that programming YouTubers are a pretty good source of keeping up to date with common gotchas, just ignore the video titles. Pulling from my watch history, watch [this video](https://youtu.be/GGo3MVBFr1A), [this video](https://youtu.be/-yIsQPp31L0), and [this video](https://youtu.be/oc_TNtCe2sY). This should seed your algorithm to suggest similar content.

Comment: @naechebango Aside from that, continue learning, in particular from other developers. There are many developers who share golden nuggets of wisdom that may have taken them years to find. Find problems to solve, understand what's the root cause and then try to explain what happened (answering on StackOverflow is great for this). Especially going forward with the oncoming use of AI this skill will become critical as developers may just become full time coaches and debuggers.